# Breaking a python loop using threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, loops

I would like to have a thread that constantly monitors the status of a value in a text file, another thread that executes some code inside a loop, and I would like that when the value in the text file changes, immediately break the loop and execute an else statement regardless of which part in the loop the program is. Is it possible to do this?

This is my python3 code:

```
import threading
import time

text_list = ['a']

def readfile():
    global text_list
    while True:
        with open("data.txt") as f: 
            text_list = f.readlines()

        # Removing new line "\n" character
        text_list = [x.strip() for x in text_list]
         
def printloop():
    while str(text_list[0]) == 'a':    
        for n in range(0,5):
            print('File Character: '+str(text_list[0])+', Iteration: '+str(n))
            time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print('File Character: '+str(text_list[0])+', Loop Broken')
        

t1 = threading.Thread(target=readfile, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=printloop)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

and this is the content of data.txt

```
a
```

The problem is that when I execute the code, I have to wait for the time.sleep function to be finished. I would like to break the loop as soon as my variable changes. I think a workaround might be to tell the time.sleep function to wait less time and increase the number of iterations, or to use something like the mills() function in Arduino, but I think it would be better for me to keep the time.sleep function as it is because my real loop in my file is much bigger and I use more than one time.sleep functions, so is there a way to break a loop if a variable changes regardless of in which part is it?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the *watchdog* module

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably do not want to unproductively continuously re-reading your input file if it has not changed. Per the suggestion made by DarkNight, you might wish to look into the `watchdog` module on the `PyPi` repository. Here we will just look at the initial modification time on the file and only re-read it if it has changed (we will check the modification time every .1 seconds). Second, in your original code, if another process is opening the file then before any writes are done its length will be 0. So you have a race condition where your `readfile` thread could be reading this 0-length file and setting `text_list` accordingly. This could result in the expression `text_list[0]` raising an exception. Here, since we are only reading the file when its modification time has changed, which appears to be *after* the new data has been written and the file closed, this is not a problem unless there are two such file rewrites being performed one after another. But to be safe, we will still check for temporary 0-length file contents.

The solution to your issue is to use a `threading.Condition` instance that represents a file contents change having occurred. Thread `printloop` will wait for up to 5 seconds for this to event to occur. If the 5 seconds have elapsed or the file has changed, the thread will wake up and perform its test. In your original code even if the file has changed, it will still still  loop up to 5 times printing messages before it terminates. I have changed the code so that this does not occur.

I have renamed function `readfile` to `monitor_file` and created a `read_file` function, used by `monitor_file` that just re-reads the file contents and returns the results.

```py
import threading
import time
import os

file_changed = threading.Condition()

PATH = 'data.txt'

def read_file():
    with open(PATH) as f:
        # Removing new line "\n" character in each line:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

# Get actual initial modification time and file contents.
# Note the order in which these two operations occur in case
# the file is modified immediately after we have done this initial read:
modification_time = os.stat(PATH)
text_list = read_file()

def monitor_file():
    global modifcation_time, text_list

    while True:
        time.sleep(.1)
        new_modification_time = os.stat(PATH)
        if new_modification_time == modification_time:
            # The file has not changed:
            continue

        modifcation_time = new_modification_time
        new_text_list = read_file()
        # Make sure not 0 length:
        if new_text_list:
            text_list = new_text_list
            if text_list[0] != 'a':
                # Tell other thread that the file has changed:
                with file_changed:
                    file_changed.notify()

def printloop():
    n = 0
    # text_list is already a list of strings
    while text_list[0] == 'a':
        # Use an f-string:
        print(f'File Character: {text_list[0]}, Iteration: {n}')
        # Wait for up to 5 seconds to see if the file has
        # changed:
        with file_changed:
            file_changed.wait(5)
            n += 1
    else:
        print(f'File Character: {text_list[0]}, Loop Broken')


t1 = threading.Thread(target=monitor_file, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=printloop)

t1.start()
t2.start()
# Wait for printloop to end:
t2.join()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great to substitute `time.sleep(5)`, but how can I break printloop() if I have something inside the function like this: `for p in range(0, 1000000000):` and then `print(p)`, I still have to wait for that to finish

Comment: Does your *new* `printloop` still have a call to `sleep` or `wait`? If not, you have changed the question. You can use a `threading.Event` instance or even a plain Boolean variable that can be checked on each iteration of the loop to decide whether to break out or not.

Comment: well, in my original code I have calls to sleep and also many different for loops, I thought I could use plain Boolean variables that could be checked on each iteration, but since I have many different loops, I felt that could make my code harder to read for me, so I was trying to look a solution that could break the whole loop at once without having to use multiple if statements to check the status of each Boolean variable on each for loop. I feel if I do that, that's going to make my code look like a complete unnecessary mess

Comment: I feel the code is not going to look clean

Answer (score 0):

Your program can be simplified by using watchdog.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

file_name = 'data.txt'
file_path = Path(__file__).with_name('data.txt').resolve()
dir_path = file_path.parent


class FileWatch(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        src_path = event.src_path
        src = Path(src_path).relative_to(dir_path).__str__()
        if src != file_name:
            print(f'{src!r} changed but it is not {file_name!r}')
            return
        text = file_path.read_text().strip()
        print('File Character:', text)
        if text == 'a':
            print('Not changed')
            return
        print('Changed; stop the observer')
        observer.stop()


observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(FileWatch(), path=dir_path, recursive=False)
observer.start()
observer.join()

"""
In Python, f-strings, also known as "formatted string literals,"
are a way to embed expressions inside string literals, using curly braces {}.
The expressions inside the curly braces are evaluated at runtime and then
formatted and substituted into the resulting string using the format specified.

In the given f-string f'{src!r} changed but it is not {file_name!r}',
src and file_name are variables or expressions whose values will be inserted
into the string.
The !r after the variable name inside the curly braces is a format specifier,
which means to use the repr() representation of the variable.
The repr() representation is a string representation of the object that,
when passed to eval(), would produce an object equivalent to the original.
In other words, it’s a string representation that includes quotes around
string objects.

So, this f-string is saying: "Evaluate src and file_name, convert them to
their repr() representation (add quotes around if they are strings),
and then insert them into the resulting string at their respective places."
"""
```

You probably need to install watchdog. You can do so by running `python -m pip install watchdog`, for example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).